# Android same attribute name in two libs, name collision

Tags: android, android-build

I'm using two 3rd party libs, both use the same attribute name in their attrs.xml. The build fails with:

```
Attribute "tabBackground" has already been defined
```

Is there a way to work around this collision without modifying the argument name in one of the libs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually no.

I suppose you have a dependency from A project to B.

When you build your main project in Eclipse, the resources will fail to build and an error is printed out in the Android console: `"... error: Attribute "icon" has already been defined"`.

Actually you have two ways :

- remove dependency from A project to B
- OR change attribute name of some project

Also if you build project with Gradle you can use [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging) article which explains how to merge resources.